# HttpXMLRequest getting stuck

Tags: javascript

I'l just trying to pick up using the HttpXMLRequest object in JS and I've got a basic loop that loads name and age from an XML file and throws it into a table. If each sibling has the same values then it loads fine, however if one of the elements is missing from a sibling it stops rather than just skips it. Heres some code.

The HTML -

```
(The rest of the XML parser and DTD, html, body etc is up here)
<script>
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("person");

document.write("<table border='1'>");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  var name = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var age = x[i].getElementsByTagName("age")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>"+name+"</td>");
  document.write("<td>"+age+"</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

The XML -

```
(The DTD and stuff it up here)
<people>
  <person>
    <name>Jim</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Bob</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Tom</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>James</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>Richie</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </person>
</people>
```

From that example, the HTML will stop after writing once it gets to bob, I assume there needs to be a try/catch or an if in there for each name and age, but I can't seem to place it so it works. Anybody got any ideas?

I've tried to search but I don't know what this issue is called, and describing it doesn't come up with anything.

Simply adding "`<age />` or `<age></age>`" isn't an option, eventually I'll be working with massive xml files. Unless I need to write something that will automatically add it if it doesn't exist, that's acceptable I guess.

Cheers Hombries.

Comment: Did you not check the console for error messages? It would give you the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check existence of element before trying to access its child nodes:

```js
var personElem = x[i];

var ageElems = personElem.getElementsByTagName("age");

var age = ageElems.length
        ? ageElems[0].firstChild.nodeValue
        : '';
```

By the way, it's typically easier to use JSON instead of XML. With JSON, your response could look like this:

```js
{
    "people": [
        {
            "name" : "Jim",
            "age" : 20
        },
        {
            "name" : "Bob"
        }
    ]
}
```

And you could access items with dot syntax:

```js
var age = data.people[0].age;
```

For example, PHP has built-in function for encoding JSON: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Is this the correct way to incorporate your suggestion simply to replace age variable with yours + the if statement? If so that still doesn't seem to work. How does it know what personElem is? Is that a built in function? I'll take a look a the JSON later because that certainly looks interesting, Thanks!

Comment: `personElem` corresponds to `x[i]` in your case. I've updated code fragment in my answer to make it more easy to just drop into your code. Probably you have to learn more about [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript) and [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) in general.

Comment: Code worked perfectly so I'm going to accept the answer now, although I do have to point out your powers of observation are second to none @ "Probably you have to learn more about JavaScript and DOM in general.". Ya' think? Cheers anyway ;)